# FilePicker in iOS 9.3 Exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios9.3

Trying to implement file picker on a device that runs on iOS 9.3

The capabilities are ticked inside Entitlements.plist and the code works on simulated device running iOS 12.2. Also tried to simulate other devices running iOS 9.3 and the result is the same

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.FilePicker;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CrossfileTest
{

    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void BrowseBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
                Debug.WriteLine("this file " + file.FileName);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("it blew up! " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}```

This is the exception I get on iOS 9.3:
  at CrossfileTest.MainPage.BrowseBtn_Clicked (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00029] in C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\CrossfileTest\CrossfileTest\CrossfileTest\MainPage.xaml.cs:27  0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bba4d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c520deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bba4bea +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010a7fcd5a -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001093485c5 -[UIDocumentPickerViewController _commonInitWithCompletion:] + 370
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010934a442 -[UIDocumentPickerViewController initWithDocumentTypes:inMode:] + 411
    6   CrossfileTest.iOS                   0x0000000102c25539 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
    7   ???                                 0x000000011f6039ee 0x0 + 4821367278

Ideas on how to fix this?
````

Comment: `UIDocumentPickerViewController ` has two different events on iOS 9 and iOS 12 which must be causing the issue you might wanna raise a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously the crash inside the plug-in. You may post the issue on their github in order to be fixed.

There is a difference in how `UIDocumentPickerViewController` works on iOS 9 and iOS 12, so there is nothing particularly strange if it works on one and not on another.

Comment: Have two different events on a document picked, that's all

Comment: So, the solution would be to ask somewhere else

Comment: To conclude, your other option is to use the native code and implement pickers for iOS and Android yourself, or to fix the plugin code as it is open source. This is probably a bit too advanced for your current level, so your best bet is to report the issue and wait for it to be fixed.